# Wordpress looping through posts setting thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to loop through all posts in Wordpress and set a thumbnail image if the post doesn't have one. I am using the following code in the functions file:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'posts');
$loop = new WP_Query($args);

while ($loop->have_posts()):
    $loop->the_post();
    $attach_id = '13057';

    if (has_post_thumbnail())
    {
        // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    }
    else
    {     
        add_post_meta($loop->ID, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id); 
    }

endwhile;
```

It doesn't seem to be working though its just having no effect on the posts whatsoever, I would really appreciate your input, many thanks in advance.

Comment: "It doesn't seem to be working though" In what way isn't it working? What errors are you getting? What unexpected output is being displayed?

Comment: Sorry should have been clearer, its just having no effect on posts at all

Comment: You might want to check out [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-set-a-default-fallback-image-for-wordpress-post-thumbnails/) and [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/default-thumbnail-plus/)

Comment: Oh, there's a typo in your code: `$args = array('post_type' => 'post');`. Singular `post`, not `posts`. I'll delete my answer until you confirm.

Comment: @brasofilo - Thanks for your help, still no joy with that unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not sure what's wrong with your code, but maybe this can clarify things: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753).

Using `get_posts()` works for me:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'post_status' => array('publish','future','draft')
);
$get = get_posts( $args );
if( $get )
{
    $attach_id = 661; // Valid attachment ID in my system
    foreach( $get as $post )
    {
        if ( !has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) )
            add_post_meta( $post->ID, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, not sure what I was doing wrong but that worked a treat!

Comment: Nice! I generally don't touch `WP_Query`, WP is kinda sensitive for it. `get_posts` is pretty straight forward.